# How do I allow access to a web server on an ISP that shares one IP address among all customers?

Tags: web-server, ip-address, wide-area-network, isp

I'm a customer of a wireless ISP that shares one WAN IP address among all customers. If any of the ISP's clients log on to whatismyip.com, they will see the exact same IP address, which will look something like 103.xxx.xxx.x.

Under these circumstances, how exactly would I go about creating a web server (for testing, just a simple one using [mongoose](https://code.google.com/archive/p/mongoose)) and allowing it access from the internet?

Is this simply a matter of choosing a port that has not already been taken? For example, if another customer creates a web server on the port 6271, should I simply choose a different port like 6272, which no other customer has used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You generally don't. These systems use something like carrier grade NAT to share a single public IP meaning you would need ISP assistance to configure this. You're unlikely to get that.

Comment: I've heard some people on my ISP do get ISP assistance to set up a server for security cameras so that the feed can be viewed remotely. How exactly is this achieved? Can you elaborate on what you mean by "ISP assistance"? What exactly do they do?

Comment: He means getting the ISP to configure a port forward for you, which they won't do. Either host your server elsewhere, switch ISPs, or upgrade to a service where you get a dedicated public IP.

Comment: Well, it seems my ISP does do this on request (it's a small ISP), specifically for security camera setups. Anyway, I asked this question purely out of academic interest.

Comment: @Vikram Excellent, there's your answer then!